# Diagram distance between two elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have the following diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset {
    block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners,text centered, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width = 9em, font=\bfseries},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, >=latex']

\node [block] (convergencia) {convergence};

\node [below right=2em] (analitica) {analitical solution};
\node [below left=2em] (numerica) {numerical solution};
\draw [<->] (analitica) -- (numerica);

\node [block,above left of=convergencia] (consistencia) {consistency};
\draw [thick,->] (consistencia) -- (convergencia);

\node[above left of=consistencia] (discreta) {Discrete equation};
\node[above right  of=consistencia] (diferencial) {differential equation};
\draw [<->] (discreta) -- (diferencial);

\node [block, above right of=convergencia] (estabilidade) {stability};
\draw [thick,->] (estabilidade) -- (convergencia);

\node[above left of=estabilidade] (exata) {exact numerical solution};
\node[above right  of=estabilidade] (numerica) {found numerical solution};
\draw [<->] (exata) -- (numerica);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it has two issues that I can't solve:

First, I can't make positional references as `above right of=object` and `above left of=object` and have a good distance between the object below and the two objects created above. By good I mean, a small vertical distance and a horizontal distance that to not clutter everything.

Second, my two boxes *Consistencia* and *Estabilidade* are nicely positioned, but the objects above them get over each other, how can I enforce a bigger horizontal distance (but not vertical) between them to make the objects above do not overwrite each other?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). What strikes me is the fact that you are loading the `positioning` library, but you are not using it. By using it, e.g. `above left=1.5cm of estabilidade` instead of `above left of=estabilidade` you should be able to place everything where you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. 1. I think that is my MWE, since without 3 elements I would not be able to show the issues; 2. I thought that ```(elem) -- (elem)``` and ```left of``` like statements is the ```poistioning``` library; 3. your hint is good, It has worked for the blocks, but the [attribs] now are  too spread horizontaly since they are starting after the margins of the [blocks]. I wish something in between. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Ok. MWE must be fully functional. All right, right on the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tikzlibrary` `positioning` allows fine-tuning the position of your nodes.

See: [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)

I have also put the description in multiple lines, otherwise, they are too long and the image goes out of the page borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc} 
\tikzset {
    block/.style = {
        draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners,text centered,  rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width = 9em, font=\bfseries
    },
    descr/.style = {
        text width=5em, 
        text centered,
        minimum height=10ex
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']

    \node [block] (convergencia) {convergence};

    \node [below right=20pt and 10pt, descr] (analitica) {analitical solution};
    \node [below left=20pt and 10pt, descr] (numerica) {numerical solution};
    \draw [<->] (analitica) -- (numerica);

    \node [block, above left= 26pt and -10pt of convergencia] (consistencia) {consistency};
    \draw [thick,->] (consistencia) -- (convergencia);

    \node[above left=5pt and -30pt of consistencia, descr] (discreta) {Discrete\\ equation};
    \node[above right=5pt and -30pt of consistencia, descr] (diferencial) {differential\\ equation};
    \draw [<->] (discreta) -- (diferencial);

    \node [block, above right=26pt and -10pt of convergencia] (estabilidade) {stability};
    \draw [thick,->] (estabilidade) -- (convergencia);

    \node[above left= 5pt and -30pt of estabilidade, descr] (exata) {exact numerical solution};
    \node[above right= 5pt and -30pt of estabilidade, descr] (numerica) {found numerical solution};
    \draw [<->] (exata) -- (numerica);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible (maybe more elegant) solution is with a `tikz` `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}  
\tikzset {
    block/.style = {
        draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners,text centered,  rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width = 9em, font=\bfseries
    },
    descr/.style = {
        text width=5em, 
        text centered,
        minimum height=10ex,
        anchor=center
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \matrix[
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep=-35pt,
        row sep=4pt,
        row 1/.style={nodes={descr}},
        row 2/.style={nodes={block}},
        row 3/.style={nodes={block}},
        row 4/.style={nodes={descr}},
        ](mymatr){  
        |[name=discreta]| Discrete equation
            & &|[name=diferencial]| differential equation 
            & &|[name=exata]| exact numerical solution 
            & &|[name=foundnumerica]| found numerical solution\\
        &|[name=consistencia]| consistency 
            & & & &|[name=estabilidade]| stability\\[20pt]
        & & &|[name=convergencia]| convergence\\
        & &|[name=analitica]| analitical solution
            & & |[name=numerica]| numerical solution\\
    };
    \draw [<->] (analitica) -- (numerica);
    \draw [thick,->] (consistencia) -- (convergencia);
    \draw [<->] (discreta) -- (diferencial);
    \draw [thick,->] (estabilidade) -- (convergencia);
    \draw [<->] (exata) -- (foundnumerica);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]